# If $U \subseteq V$ is an open set, Then $T(U) \subseteq V'$ is also an open set

Tags: vector-spaces, continuity, normed-spaces

Definitions:

Assume that $(V,||.||)$ and $(V',||.||')$ are two normed spaces.
We say a function $f:(V,||.||) \to (V',||.||')$ is continuous on a point $a \in V$ if:
$\forall \epsilon \gt 0\space\space\exists \delta \gt 0\space\space||x-a||\lt \delta \implies ||f(x)-f(a)||' \lt \epsilon$

---

We say a function $f$ is a homeomorphism if both $f$ and $f^{-1}$ are continuous.

---

Question:

Assume that $T:(V,||.||) \to (V',||.||')$ is a homeomorphism.

Prove that:

> If $U \subseteq V$ is an open set, Then $T(U) \subseteq V'$ is also an
>   open set.

Note: The only thing that we know about $f$ is that its homeomorphism. But, How should we use it to reach the conclusion of the  above statement? (That's my problem)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hint: $U=T^{-1}(T(U))$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\forall U \subset V$, $U$ open $\implies U=T^{-1}(T(U))$; now, by continuity of $T^{-1}$, $T(U)$ is open in $V'$

Comment: Thanks for the answer... would u please explain the last part? (How did u conclude that $T(U)$ is open? How is it related to the continuity of $T^{-1}$?

Comment: $f:W\to Z$ is open $\iff \forall A\subset Z$, $A$ open, then $f^{-1}(A)$ is open in $W$ (pretty easy demonstration). In your case, $f=T^{-1}$, $W=V'$, $Z=V$, $A=U$, $T(U)=T^{-1}(A)$